# Ternary operator usage issue

Tags: c, ternary-operator

I have used ternary operator before for a condition like `if-else` but here it's different i.e. not checking a condition before `?`.

```
  printf( "%d\n",10?0?5:11:12 );
```

**Edited**:
So,how will it evaluate `11` as by compiler because i don't see any condition before first `?`.

Comment: You now the syntax of the ternary operator? `(condition)?TRUE:FALSE`

Comment: @Rizier123 Condition in C can be a integer value. So it syntactically correct.

Comment: Why downvote?Are scholars only allowed here.Isn't it a learning platform???

Comment: Probably because your question is not clear. For example, there are two `?`. It isn't clear what you are asking, or why you would expect anything other than 11.

Comment: It's demand to be two `(?)` not my choice

Comment: Hate this downvote button now

Comment: @Prabu I know i meant it more for understanding

Comment: Edited question now for more clarity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression `10 ? 0 ? 5 : 11 : 12` is parsed this way: `10 ? (0 ? 5 : 11) : 12`. So this means that in the first test, since 10 is true, it will evaluate `0 ? 5 : 11`, which evaluates to 11 since 0 is false.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression is parsed as `10?(0?5:11):12` and the inner conditional expression `(0?5:11)` is constant folded to `11` then the entire expression is constant folded to `11` (since `10` is true since non-zero).

Notice that a condition (such as the first test operand of a [`?:` ternary conditional expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:)) can be any scalar, non-`void`, expression. In particular `11` is a valid condition.

Answer (score 1):

It will be solved in this manner

```
printf("%d\n",10?0?5:11:12);
```

i.e `10?(0?5:11):12`

First solve `0?5:11` as 0 means false so it will return `11`.

Now Condition will be like `10?11:12`

As `10` is non zero condition will be true, so it will return `11`.

Answer (score 1):

`printf( "%d\n",10?0?5:11:12 );` is of syntax `(condition)?TRUE:FALSE`

There are *two* ternary operators. For better readibility and understanding, let's put it this way

```
(10 ? (0 ? 5 : 11) : 12)
```

So, the inner condition, `(0 ? 5 : 11)` checks whether `0` is `TRUE` or `FALSE`. It is a `FALSE` value, [yes, zero is considered as `FALSE`  and non-zero value is considered as `TRUE` and both are perfectly valid sysntax for conditional check]. so , it evaluates to `11`.

Now, for the outer condition, the code *appears* as `(10 ? 11 : 12)`. Following simmilar logic, `10` being a `TRUE`, it returns `11`. which is passed to `printf()`. That's how you get your output.

Answer (score 0):

What is going on is in pseudo code a little bit:

(But in the ternary operator first the inner ternary condition get's "calculated")

```
if (10) {  //true
    if(0) {  //false
        print 5
    } else {
        print 11  //Output 11
    }

} else {
    print 12
}
```

Or as a ternary operator but a little bit more readable:

```
(10 ? (0 ? 5 : 11) : 12)
```

Comment: No, ternary conditional operator is for expressions, not statements!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch My example should show the code line in a bit pseudo code